# Why the backbone of polylactic acid's repeating unit contains only one oxygen?

Tags: polymers

The monomer unit of polylactic acid is $\ce{CH_3-CH(OH)-CO_2H}$:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acid]

So why the backbone of the repeating unit is $\ce{-C-C-O -}$:

[image]

and not $\ce{-O-C-C-O -}$?

Comment: Can you draw a mechanism for the condensation of two molecules of lactic acid?

Comment: @orthocresol what do you mean?

Comment: How is the polymer formed from its monomers? Can you draw a mechanism for this?

Comment: @orthocresol both ways seem fine. in other words, why the polymer doesn't have O-O bonds all over? why water is released and not H2?

Comment: I believe there is only one way that "seems fine". You need to be able to draw a *mechanism*. I do not mean "draw the products", because if all you look at is the product, it will be hard to tell what makes sense and what does not make sense. So, I mean "draw a mechanism", with all the curly arrows and whatnot. If you can do so, then you will see why you do not form O-O bonds all over the place.

Comment: @Sparkler If you want a rule of thumb, O-O bonds are a big red warning sign, so is releasing $\ce{H2}$ (unless you have a metal around, which is not the case), and combining both of them together is not just impossible, it is **ten times impossible**.

Comment: a hint: PET (but here, you have single monomer)